# Tmux: How to join 4 sessions into 4 horizontally panes

Tags: terminal, tmux

If I have four sessions called `PP1`, `PP2`, `PP3`, and `PP4`, how would I join them so that they would look something like this:

```
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
|PP1|PP2|PP3|PP4|
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
```

Currently I'm using join pane, but am unsure of how to make them evenly spaced.

```
tmux join-pane -h -s PP2 -t PP1
tmux join-pane -h -s PP3 -t PP1
tmux join-pane -h -s PP4 -t PP1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-b + Spacebar` will switch between predefined layouts. There's even-spaced vertical, horizontal, etc.

Just in case, that's `Ctrl+b` release and then press `Spacebar`

A bro-tip: you can issue the join pane inside tmux. Try this, on the session PP1 do `C-b + :` type `j` press `tab` and you'll get `join-pane` autocompleted then add `-hs PP2`. Now do `C-b + :` again and press the `up` key, replace the 2 for a 3 and so on. Finally do the `C-b + Spacebar` to space even.